Mostrar los datos pares de una matriz FxC
Tengo que que crear una matriz y en esa matriz buscar y mostrar los números pares que contenga, ya lo tengo hecho, recorrí la matriz y los datos pares los guardé en un arreglo creado previamente, pero el arreglo tiene las dimensiones de la matriz original por lo tanto cuando tengo una cantidad de números pares menor a la dimensión del arreglo me da ceros, lo que necesito es saber como puedo hacer para usar la cantidad de números pares que tenga como dimensión del arreglo. Esto es lo que tengo:
public int[] datoPar(){
    int n = matriz.GetLength(0)*matriz.GetLength(1);
    int t =0;
    int[] arregloPar = new int[n];
        
    for (int fila=0; fila<matriz.GetLength(0); fila++){
        for(int columna=0; columna<matriz.GetLength(1); columna++){
            
            if( matriz[fila, columna] % 2 != 0){
                if (matriz[fila, columna] % 2 == 0){
                    arregloPar[t] = matriz[fila,columna];
                    t++;
                }
            }
            else{
                arregloPar[t] = matriz[fila,columna];
                t++;
            }
        }           
    }

    return arregloPar;       
}


Hola Josue, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles y en caso de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado, gracias

En vez de usar un arreglo para almacenar los números pares puedes usar una lista de enteros, la cual no tiene un tamaño predefinido, sino que crece o decrece dinámicamente según sea el caso. Por otra parte para recorrer la matriz puedes usar un foreach de esta forma te ahorras un ciclo for:
List<int> pares = new List<int>();

foreach(var n in matriz)
{
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        pares.Add(n);
    }
}

En este código se recorre cada número de la matriz y de ser par se almacena en la lista pares.

Un array tiene una longitud fija, asignada al momento de crearla (esto es cierto para muchos lenguajes, pero hay excepciones).
El reemplazante natural de un array es una Lista, el cual tiene una dimensión dinámica. Generalmente en los cursos de programación se enseña esto en estructura de datos, donde aprendes a crear "Listas enlazadas", "Listas doblemente enlazadas", "Listas circulares", etc. (Supongo que no has llegado a ese punto)
C# cuenta con varias implementaciones de Listas, la más común es List:
int[] array = new int[100]; //creación de un array de int
List<int> lista = new List<int>(); //creación de una lista de int

//otras variantes para crear una lista, que han aparecido en nuevas versiones con el fin de simplicar
var lista = new List<int>();
List<int> lista = new();

Entonces tu programa quedaría (corregí un tema de losif que sobran):
//public List<int> datoPar() //para devolver la lista
public int[] datoPar()
{
    int n = matriz.GetLength(0) * matriz.GetLength(1);
    List<int> arregloPar = new List<int>();

    for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.GetLength(0); fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < matriz.GetLength(1); columna++)
        {
            if (matriz[fila, columna] % 2 == 0)
            {
                arregloPar.Add(matriz[fila, columna]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arregloPar.ToArray(); //puedes convertir la lista a array
    //return arregloPar; // si es que quieres retornar la lista "public List<int> datoPar()"

}

Por otro lado, si por temas académicos no puedes utilizar List, lo más simple es recorrer 2 veces la matriz.

Recorres la matriz y cuentas los pares
Creas el array
Recorres para llenar el array

public int[] datoPar()
{
    int n = matriz.GetLength(0) * matriz.GetLength(1);
    int size = 0;

    for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.GetLength(0); fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < matriz.GetLength(1); columna++)
        {
            if (matriz[fila, columna] % 2 == 0)
            {
                size++;
            }
        }
    }

    int[] arregloPar = new int[size];
    int t = 0;
    for (int fila = 0; fila < matriz.GetLength(0); fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < matriz.GetLength(1); columna++)
        {
            if (matriz[fila, columna] % 2 == 0)
            {
                arregloPar[t] = matriz[fila, columna];
                t++;
            }
        }
    }
    return arregloPar; 
          
}

